# How to make stage appear with correct size when using MigLayout with JavaFX

Tags: javafx, miglayout, stage

I am trying to have the stage appear with the size auto adjusted to the content.

In Swing I would always call JFrame.pack(), regardless of the LayoutManager, in swt it would happen automatically when calling Window.open()

In JavaFX this also seems to happen automatically when using something like HBox:

```
Stage s = new Stage();
HBox p = new HBox(5);
for (int i=0;i<3;i++)
    p.getChildren().add(new Button("Hello"));
s.setScene(new Scene(p));
s.showAndWait()
```

When using MigPane however, the original layout is incorrect:

```
Stage s = new Stage();
MigPane p = new MigPane();
for (int i=0;i<3;i++)
    p.add(new Button("Hello"));
s.setScene(new Scene(p));
s.showAndWait();
s.showAndWait();
```

I can't post images, but the first call shows the window too small with only the top of the buttons visible. The second call shows it with correct layout.

How can I get it too appear correctly the first time?

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug in MigPane.[(see here)](https://code.google.com/p/miglayout/issues/detail?id=8)

It is fixed in miglayout-javafx-5.0-SNAPSHOT (needs java8).